# Entity Framework Core async join yields no results in SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I have two tables and I intend to join and filter them with Entity Framework Core in a SQLite database.

I use the following queries:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Person>> GetPerson(Guid key, int type)
{
  var mainTable = dbContext.Person.ToListAsync(); //470 entities
  var detailTable = dbContext.PersonDetail.ToListAsync(); //490 entities
  var filterDetail = dbContext.PersonDetail.Where(pd=> pd.DetailID == key).ToList(); //160 entities
  var query = from person in dbContext.Person
              join personDetail in dbContext.PersonDetail on person.ID equals personDetail.PersonID
              where personDetail.DetailID == key && personDetail.DetailType == type
              select person;
  return await query.ToListAsync(); //yields 0 (!!!!) entities
}
```

If I remove the `person.DetailID == key` condition, I still get some results.

If I query both entites to a list, the `DetailID` is equal to the `key`:

```
  var query = from person in dbContext.Person
              join personDetail in dbContext.PersonDetail on person.ID equals personDetail.PersonID
              where personDetail.DetailType == type
              select new {person, personDetail};
  var result = query.ToListAsync(); 
  return null; //result[0].personDetail.DetailID == key yields TRUE!!!
```

What should I do with this? Does the async part cause the problem?

Comment: it could be that `person.DetailID == key` is always `true`

Comment: You are using different criteria in the query `person.DetailID == key` and the verification `personDetail.DetailID == key`. It's unclear what's the purpose of the `DetailID` field in the `Person` class.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes, the code was incomplete, but using the proper variable, there is still no result.